# How do I skip an offline database over the network in MySQL import?

Tags: mysql, restore, command-line

I am doing a MySQL import from an *.sql file to multiple database location over the network. I'm using cmd batch file to run the command and it's working as I expect it to be. However I notice that the import took longer times on any IP that is offline compared to the ones that is online. Below are the duration it took for both processes:

1. If online : 7-8 secs average/process
2. If offline : 40 secs average/process

Each of the process is performing two command, one is to import an *.sql file and the other is referring a *.txt file to update a table in the same location I imported the *.sql file.

```
Command 1:
mysql.exe -h 192.xxx.xxx.xxx -P 3306 -u root -pxxxx db < C:\xxx\data\xxx.sql

Command 2:
mysql.exe -h 192.xxx.xxx.xxx -P 3306 -u root -pxxxx db < update.txt
```

These commands is repeated about 20 times in one batch file and the possibility of getting an offline database is high. If I'm lucky, I'll get only one or two offline location but to get all database online at once is highly unlikely. The *.sql file is just about 45MB in size so import is actually quick.

My question is, how do I skip the offline location?

Comment: What do you mean while using "offline" term?

Comment: When the batch file run and detects the IP cannot be connected therefore it cannot perform the sql import - hence, offline.

Comment: Simple remote node ping test may say does this IP is available for to connect to in general. TCP ping test by node's MySQL port may say does the MySQL service is available on this node. Check this before executing import/update commands, and set timeouts small enough. Or at least check the 1st command result for a connection error.

Comment: @Akina ,based on your comment I search for "IF ping ELSE in cmd" and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245545/ping-test-using-bat-file-trouble-with-errorlevel . My initial testing seems to work now I'm just checking whether all processes are successful. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd recommend to concat all your scripts before execution. You'll save time needed to start mysql.exe 39 times... Of course check that the concatenated script size does not exceed max_allowed_packet.

Comment: Could you give me an example or a link to how can I concat as you suggested? I'm very interested in that

Comment: *how can I concat as you suggested?* `copy C:\xxx\data\*.sql+C:\xxx\data\*.txt %TEMP%\wholescript.sql`, then import this file, then delete it if not needed for to apply to another node (may be specified by .BAT parameter).

Comment: So instead I just need to do this `mysql.exe -h 192.xxx.xxx.xxx -P 3306 -u root -pxxxx db < %TEMP%\wholescript.sql` , is this correct @Akina ?

Comment: Yes. The only restriction is that you cannot detect a separate problematic script if an error occures during import in such case.

Comment: Maybe I can include a command to log the process externally and capture if there's any error from there?

Comment: If you really need in error debugging I'd recommend to create some service table and a script which inserts the record with some info into this table. Then you may add this debugging script between separate conactenated scripts. Looking the service table you may define what script causes the error, and get some info about it.

Comment: Got it. I'll take a look at that. Thank you very much for your help @Akina . I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some suggestion from Akina, I'm able to find one post in SO about how to determine if an IP is online or not through the network before executing the MySQL import command. Here is the link to the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21252613/10910692

Below is the code I'm using in my batch file:

```
ping -n 1 192.xxx.xxx.xx | find "TTL=" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo host is offline..
    ) else (
    echo Updating host...
    mysql.exe -h 192.xxx.xxx.xx -P -u -p inventory < C:\xxx\data\xxx.sql
)
```

I also took Akina's suggestion to concatenate both the import and update query into one file and only need to call that one file for the update. As I mention in my question, the code above is repeated for about 20 times.

If I stick to my previous method and assuming that all IP is offline, it will take about 800 secs = 13-14 mins for the batch file to finish processing while with the method above, it reduces to 1-2 mins only! (based on assumption that each command took 5 secs max while in reality its less than 5 secs per command).